# Recursive function program- Logical error in calculating sum of a series

Tags: c++, recursion

I was writing a C++ program to calculate the sum of a series:

[image]

So I wrote a recursive function as such:

```
double func(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return pow(1/n, n) + func(n-1);
}
```

For the following series, 
when `n` is `1`, then `sum` is: `1`  
when `n` is `2`, then `sum` is: `1.25`  
when `n` is `3`, the `sum` is `1.3611`

But the above code when executed, returns `1` for all values of `n`.
Somebody please tell me what's behind this??

Comment: try using float or double as int does not store decimal numbers

Comment: Yes, I have used double as the return data type.

Comment: Have you tried `1.0/n`?

Answer (score 2):

Because `n` is an integer, `1/n` will always yield an integer result because the compiler infers that 1 is an integer.

Changing it to `1.0/n`, however, will yield a double result.